# How can I determine the download speed and amount from LWP::Simple's getstore()?

Tags: perl, download, lwp

When using the perl module [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.834/lib/LWP/Simple.pm), is there a simple way to determine the speed and amount downloaded by a single getstore() invocation?  This would be useful for observing the status of large file downloads.

Off the top of my head, one approach would be to:

1. store the current time (time0)
2. run getstore in a new process
3. poll the known destination file

   - the amount downloaded would be the current file size (size)
   - the download speed would (size / current_time - time0)

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way.

Alternative suggestions welcome (perhaps I should use a different module?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have other requirements (such as watching the rate and size during the download), the steps that you outlined are the easiest to think about and implement.

You can export the underlying user-agent object in LWP::Simple. If you just want to watch the download for a one-off, you can set the `show_progress` bit of the user-agent:

```
 use LWP::Simple qw($ua getstore);

 $ua->show_progress(1);

 getstore( 
'http://www.theperlreview.com/Issues/subscribers.html',
'subscribers.html'
);
```

To do more work, you can use LWP::Simple and still do the [same thing ysth suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778092/determining-speed-and-amount-downloaded-by-a-single-perl-lwpsimple-getstore-i/1778148#1778148):

```
 use LWP::Simple qw($ua);

 $ua->response_header( 
      sub { 
          my($response, $ua, $h) = @_; 
          ... 
          }
      );
```

In that subroutine, you read the data and do whatever you like with it, including keeping a timer. Once you get your answer, you can delete that bit of code and go back to just `getstore`.

Flavio Poletti wrote "Watching LWP's Activity" for [The Perl Review, Spring 2009](http://www.theperlreview.com/Issues/subscribers.html) and shows many uses of this technique.

Comment: Thanks for the great response and examples.  Flavio Poletti's one page write-up was also useful and concise.

Comment: I didn't find Flavio's one-page write up concise at all. Also, this answer didn't help me. I have a very large file that I need to download, and while it downloads, I need to use named pipes to post a message back to my GUI (written in Objective C). I've got the pipes thing going, but can't yet figure out the LWP byte iterator as it downloads.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `LWP::Simple`, use [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP::UserAgent) directly.  For a starting point, look at how LWP::Simple::getstore initializes a $ua and invokes request.  You'll want to call `$ua->add_handler` to specify a `response_data` handler to do whatever you want; by default (at least for the HTTP protocol) `LWP::UserAgent` will be reading up to 4Kb chunks and call the `response_data` handler for each chunk, but you can suggest a different size in the request method parameters.

You may want to specify other handlers too, if you want to differentiate between header data and actual data that will be stored in the file or do something special if there are redirects.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew there had to be a better way.